# How to find the corresponding build to a deployment in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I want to know, what commit is deployed, not using the pipeline. I can find the build artifact s3, but now I wonder, how I can find the corresponding build in the build history.